# JSF in rendered property java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,00"

Tags: java, jsf, locale, numberformatexception, jspx

I have the following `tag` in a table row in my `jsf` page (`jspx`):

```
<af:image source="/resources/img/up.png" id="img1" rendered="#{row['percentage'] ge 0}"/>
```

From the error I can tell that `row['percentage']` is equal to `"0,00"` which causes parsing errors for *JSF*

I tried changing the `locale` by the following:

1. `<f:view locale="#{pageFlowScope.backing_bean.locale}">`

   Where in my bean I have:

   `private Locale locale = new Locale("fr");`
2. I tried to use:

   `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);`

But nothing works!

Comment: @BalusC Yep, I try to pass it as a `String` to later use it for some other purposes as well

Comment: JSF before comparing a `String` to a `Number`, it parses it, so all is thought of beforehand, but the problem is that it keeps parsing it on a US  locale, and not on the french one and obviously the comma is a big issue for that specific locale, my problem is changing the locale so that JSF would parse it correctly.